# Writing testable JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, js-test-driver

I'm starting to delve into some work with JavaScript and i'm trying to get a feel for how I should be writing testable JS code. My background is primarily Java which i'm quite comfortable with but I have no JavaScript experience. after some reading, I was going to use js-test-driver as my unit test framework, but I am open to suggestions here as well. With Java, my approach has always been breaking things down into small methods which accept something and return something... With JavaScript, I figured I would take a similar approach by separating any DOM manipulation and the actual logic into 2 separate functions. For example:

```
function sumValues(valA, valB) {
return (valA + valB);
}

function displayResult(result) {
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result';
}
```

So, any business logic would be easily testable.

Am I on the right track here or is there a better way to do things? Any recommended reading on this topic that is JS specific? Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Just wondering - what are you trying to do with that `return (valA, valB);`? In Javascript, the comma operator works like this: `(statement, return)`, so you're basically evaluating `valA` and then returning `valB`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated it with a +, typo

Comment: I have no experience doing this, however, this feels absolutely correct to me. Something you may want to look into that would actually help a lot especially coming from a Java background would be functional paradigm programming (which it sounds like you've inched towards as it is) because javascript is completely capable of being a functional lalnguage, and unit testing is a huge driver in the functional paradigm so you could look for reading materials on unit testing in the functional paradigm.

Comment: Here's a thread that details what I'm referring to, including the fact that you've stretched closer to functional in your java code: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=493963

Comment: I guess `function displayResult(result){document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result';}` should be `function displayResult(result){document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;}` (without quotes)

Comment: Your approach to organising the code for testability in this way sounds good, to me. I use jsTestDriver for specifying assertions and I use Sinon.js for spying and stubbing method calls. The two together make a very powerful TDD tool for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy and Greg for the feedback and suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking code into logical units still applies in JavaScript of course. As to how exactly you'd structure your code and organize reusability, there are many different ways to choose from - too many to list here and also a matter of personal preference. From prototypal inheritance, to pseudo-classical inheritance; using frameworks like [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [angular.js](http://www.angularjs.org/), [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), [yui](http://yuilibrary.com/), [google closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/)...

Regarding your example you'd probably start separating your code into views and controllers which are testable separately, and have only the view manipulate the DOM. I'd check out [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) for more.

A book that really helped me get started with test driven development in JavaScript (and also learn about JavaScript at the same time) is [Test-Driven JavaScript Development](http://tddjs.com/) by Christian Johansen.

I'm using JsTestDriver, it's a great software and definitely good to use. But before using it large scale I'd evaluate other products too, because development in JsTestDriver has been going really slow recently.. [Buster.JS](http://busterjs.org/) looks promising. Another interesting runner is [Testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) which allows you to use different test frameworks, like [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) and [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/).

I can also recommend [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/) as mocking toolkit.

Comment: One build - since Buster.JS is still in Beta (and doesn't currently work on Windows), going down the JsTestDriver route for now looks safe, since Buster looks like it provides a runner for JsTestDriver tests: http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/extensions/buster-jstestdriver/

Comment: Another test runner I'm currently experimenting with is [Testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem). Great if you prefer the BDD syntax, and it seems to have Windows support. No js-test-driver compatibility though.. there's a nice introduction [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/make-javascript-testing-fun-with-testem/).